# Possible Reasons Why a PHP File Upload Wouldn't Work

Tags: php, file-upload

Here is the HTML:

```
<h1>Upload Custom Logo</h1>
<form action="settings.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<input type="file" name="Logo" />
<input type="submit" value="Upload" name="logoUpload" />
</form>
```

Here is the PHP:

```
<?php /* Handle Logo Upload */
if($_POST['logoUpload']) {

$target_path = "uploads/";
$Logo = $_FILES['Logo']['name'];

$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['Logo']['name']); 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo '<div class="statusUpdate">The file '.  basename( $_FILES['Logo']['name']). 
        ' has been uploaded</div>';
    }   

} else{
    echo '<div class="statusUpdate">There was an error uploading the file to: '.$target_path.', please try again!  Error Code was: '.$_FILES['Logo']['error'].'</div>';
}

}
?>
```

It always goes to the "else" statement on that code, I have an uploads folder in the same directory as this php file set to 777 file permissions.  The image I am test uploading is under 10KB in size.  But the move_uploaded_file() always fails and it doesn't return any error message except for the custom error message made with the else statement.

Comment: `var_dump($_FILES);` and show it here

Comment: $_FILES['uploadedfile'] is not setted

Answer (score 3):

You're referring to the file in the `$_FILES` array by two different names -
`$Logo = $_FILES['Logo']['name'];`
`move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)`

Which one is it?  `Logo` or `uploadedfile` ?

You're probably referencing an array index which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Possible reasons:

- The uploading of the file failed in some way.
- You don't have permission to move the file to the target path.

As PHP.NET says:

> If filename is not a valid upload file, then no action will occur, and
>   move_uploaded_file() will return FALSE.
>
> If filename is a valid upload file, but cannot be moved for some
>   reason, no action will occur, and move_uploaded_file() will return
>   FALSE. Additionally, a warning will be issued.

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Comment: Permissions of the target path are 777, uploading of the file was successful it can read the filename.